# How to set one Prometheus alert rule for multiple nodes

Tags: prometheus, percona, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

If I have node_name like xxx,yyy,zzz . With different name

how to set this one alert rule for multiple node_name

```
- alert: DiskOutOfUsageMySQL
 expr:node_filesystem_avail_bytes{node_name=”xxx”} / node_filesystem_size_bytes{node_name=“xxx”} * 100 
 for: 5m
 labels:
  severity: warning
 annotations:
  summary: Disk out of usage (instance {{ $labels.node_name }} {{$labels.mountpoint}})
  description: "/Db is almost running out of available size (< 10% left)\n VALUE = {{ $value }}\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by replacing `{node_name=“xxx”}` with `{node_name=~“xxx|yyy|zzz”}`